# Python - vector TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration

Tags: python, vector, typeerror

I am pretty new to python and trying to follow a tutorial about vectors

I have the following code:

```
def vector_add(v, w):
    return [v_i + w_i for v_i, w_i in zip(v, w)]

def vector_subtract(v, w):
    return [v_i - w_i for v_i, w_i in zip(v, w)]

def vector_sum(vectors):
    return reduce(vector_add, vectors)  

def scalar_multiply(c, v):
    #c is a line v is a vector
    return [c * v_i for v_i in v]

def vector_mean(vectors):
    #compute the vectors whose ith element is the mean of the ith elements of the input vectors
    n = len(vectors)
    return scalar_multiply(1/n, vector_sum(vectors))
vector_mean([1,2,3,4])
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vectors.py", line 21, in <module>
    vector_mean([1,2,3,4])
  File "vectors.py", line 20, in vector_mean
    return scalar_multiply(1/n, vector_sum(vectors))
  File "vectors.py", line 11, in vector_sum
    return reduce(vector_add, vectors)  
  File "vectors.py", line 5, in vector_add
    return [v_i + w_i for v_i, w_i in zip(v, w)]
TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration
```

Im guessing this is because i am passing in an integer or something but am unsure?
Any help on why this is happening and how to fix this error would be much appreciated.
Thanks,
scott

Comment: `vector_mean` is supposed to take a list of vectors however, you pass it only one. Because of that, `zip` fails.

Answer (score 0):

```
print vector_mean([[1,2,3,4], [22,23,34,44]])
```

And fix that string to:

```
scalar_multiply(1/float(n), vector_sum(vectors))
```

(to force division to be **floating**):